# need to output error if anything EXCEPT 1 or 2 is input by user

Tags: java

So it looks like it allows me to input all ints, and when i do a string or anything else it does give me error, but how do I go about making it so its ONLY 1 and/or 2 accept and 3,4,5....(every other number) are not excepted...
Code below

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Please enter 1 to add or 2 to multiply. "); // ask user to input 1 or 2
          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
          try {
             int add = in.nextInt(); // add for 1
          int multiply = in.nextInt(); // multiply for 2 
         }
          catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println("Operation failed. You need to enter 1 or 2.");
          }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions here would be overkill IMO. Just using if else clauses would work equally well. Like this:

```
if(input == 1) {
    // add
} 
else if(input == 2) {
    // multiply
} 
else {
    System.out.println("Operation failed. You need to enter 1 or 2.");
}
```

Also if you want the program to keep prompting you can just wrap it in a loop. Here is a small example using a boolean sentinel to keep the loop going. This is one of many ways to implement this task.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please enter 1 to add or 2 to multiply. "); // ask user to input 1 or 2

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean inputNotValid = true;
    while(inputNotValid){
        int input = in.nextInt();

        if(input == 1) {
            inputNotValid = false;
            //add
            System.out.println("adding");
        } 
        else if(input == 2) {
            inputNotValid = false;
            //multiply
            System.out.println("multiplying");
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("Operation failed. You need to enter 1 or 2. Try again");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The Exception still needs to be caught. Without, the program won't compile!

Comment: @Burkhard You're right there is an exception. But it is an unchecked exception so the program still compile and ran when I tested it. However, it is still a good idea to catch it, like you did.

Comment: Not using exception is the right thing here, however, it might be useful to the OP to include a snippet throwing an exception, because apparently that was his intention and he should know how to do that in the future. +1 anyway

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
int add = in.nextInt(); // add for 1
int multiply = in.nextInt(); // multiply for 2
```

with:

```
int value = in.nextInt();
if(value == 1) // do add
if(value == 2) // do multiply
// else case = error
```

The whole program would become:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter 1 to add or 2 to multiply. ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    try
    {
        int value = in.nextInt();
        if (value == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("add");
            // do add
        }
        else if (value == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("mult");
            // do multiply
        }
        else
        {
            // error
            System.out.println("Operation failed. You need to enter 1 or 2.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Read operation failed. This should not happen!");
    }
}
```

The javadoc for nextInt() says:

```
Scans the next token of the input as an int. 

An invocation of this method of the form nextInt() behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation nextInt(radix), where radix is the default radix of this scanner.

Returns:
the int scanned from the input
Throws:
InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range
NoSuchElementException - if input is exhausted
IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed
```

You still can catch the InputMismatchException, the NoSuchElementException and the IllegalStateException, since in.nextInt() *can* throw them. You could also catch Exception (the only superclass of all three exceptions) instead.
Since Exception is an unchecked Exception, you can also remove the try-catch. Beware though, that an error in the Input will then exit the whole program.

Comment: Yeah, I need it so that if 2 is entered, it will call a method and same with 1, but if 5 is entered, it will displaying an error saying it needed to enter 1 or 2

Comment: You don't really handle the case when the input is invalid, you just print a message

Comment: `Exception` is a **checked** exception ! It is the base class of *all* checked exceptions !